# Any date function in hive can select the week of the month?

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

Is there any date function in Hive that can select the week of the month?
Suppose the week is from Sunday to Saturday and Sunday is the beginning day of the week and Saturday is the ending day of the week.

I have a list of dates ranging from 1900-01-01 till 2029-12-31. 
I want to know if there is a date function in Hive to obtain the week of month of the days.
e.g.:

```
2019-02-01 to 2019-02-02 is the first week of FEB  
2019-02-03 to 2019-02-09 is the second week of FEB..  
2019-02-24 to 2019-02-28 is the 5th week of FEB
```

Here is my query:

```
select (weekofyear(date)-weekofyear(trunc(date,'month')) + 1 as Week_of_month
```

However, some error occurs. At the beginning of the year, the week of month is negative. e.g. 1993-01-03 is -51

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_format(date/timestamp/string ts, string fmt)` [function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions). `W` format pattern means a week number in a month.

```
select date_format('2019-02-01','W');
OK
1
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select date_format('1993-01-03','W');
OK
2
Time taken: 0.054 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

[Other useful date and time format patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: This set Sunday as the first day of the week where I need a week to be Mon-Sun

How can I change this?

Comment: @Dee Please ask new question and  community will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568002/how-to-set-simpledateformat-w-use-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week-instead-of

Comment: I have  the feeling I won't get any replies, will see!

Comment: For context that's a spark question but a hive answer would help too